# getting stuck when retrieving data in firebase android

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When running this I am always getting stuck here: `databaseRefer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()` I did try different ways with the same results.

I am trying to read that node to check if that username already exist.

```
public void validateUsername(final String sUsername, final FirebaseUser user) {

    DatabaseReference databaseRefer;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    databaseRefer = mFirebaseInstance.getReference().child("TakenUserNames").child(sUsername);
    databaseRefer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                // username is already taken
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Username already exist. try a different one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // username is valid
                onAuthenticationSucess(user);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Connection Error. Please try again in some time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code

```
public void validateUsername(final String sUsername) {
        DatabaseReference databaseRefer;
        FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        databaseRefer = mFirebaseInstance.getReference().child("TakenUserNames").child(sUsername);
        databaseRefer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    // username is already taken
                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Username already exist. try a different one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // username is valid
                    onAuthenticationSucess(task.getResult().getUser());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Connection Error. Please try again in some time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Note:- When you call Firebase API, that API will run on separate thread. So in your function after the Firebase call you are returning value from boolean array. But the Firebase API call is not completed yet. So try to do the execution or run you code inside onDataChange().

Comment: Thank you but how can i wait for the execution to be done? this is what calls the function above and then it will run the onAuthenticationSucess:

`if (!validateUsername(user.getUsername())) {
onAuthenticationSucess(task.getResult().getUser());
onAuthenticationSucess(task.getResult().getUser());
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Username already exist. try a different one"
                                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }`

Comment: check the edited answer and just call `validateUsername(user.getUsername())`

Comment: if i do it that way, the task is unresolved because it is outside the createUserWithEmailAndPassword